# How do I Format my number?

Tags: swift

```
var displayValue: Double {
    get {
        return Double(display.text!)!
    }

    set {
        display.text = formatCurrency(value: newValue)
    }
}

func formatCurrency(value: Double) -> String {
    let formatter = NumberFormatter()
    formatter.numberStyle = .decimal
    formatter.alwaysShowsDecimalSeparator = false
    formatter.decimalSeparator = ","
    formatter.maximumFractionDigits = 2;
    formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: Locale.current.identifier)
    let result = formatter.string(from: value as NSNumber);
    return result!;
}

private var brain = CalculatorBrain()

@IBAction func touchDigit(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let digit = sender.currentTitle!
    if userIsInTheMiddleOfTyping {
        let textCurrentlyInDisplay = display.text!
        display.text = textCurrentlyInDisplay + digit
    } else {
        display.text = digit
        userIsInTheMiddleOfTyping = true
    }
}
```

Whenever I touch my button, the label is not being updated.
I wanted to make the "Display Label" look nice so I am using a NumberFormatter and I set the properties for my formatter

I've tried this

```
let result = String(displayValue) + formatter.string(from: value as NSNumber)!;
```

in my formatCurreny function but the behavior of my application does not allow me to press +, - (or operation keys)

Answer (score 0):

Because you format your `display` label in the setter for `displayValue` but you never set that property.

If you want your calculator's display to look "nice", you need to manage 3 variables:

- The *unformatted* text, which you use to append digits to the display
- The *formatted* text, which you want to show on the label with decimal separators and so on
- The `displayValue`, a `Double` that you use for your `CalculatorBrain`

You can design the other 2 variables around the *unformatted* text like so:

```
var unformattedText: String = "" {
    didSet {
        display.text = formatCurrency(value: displayValue)
    }
}
var displayValue: Double {
    get {
        return Double(unformattedText)!
    }
    set {
        unformattedText = String(newValue)
    }
}

@IBAction func touchDigit(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let digit = sender.currentTitle!
    if userIsInTheMiddleOfTyping {
        unformattedText += digit
    } else {
        unformattedText = digit
        userIsInTheMiddleOfTyping = true
    }
}
```